# Should I upvote an answer from a deleted user?

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes, deleted-users

So I came up with this question today [Stray start tag script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958667/stray-start-tag-script) and the only answer it was given by a user who isn't currently part of the SO community (I really don't know why).

Every time a user is removed from SO and happened to vote in one of my answers, my rep is taken down those points I earned, Which is understandable.

My doubt is, should this answer still be available? if so, should I upvote this question knowing that won't make any good to the user?

Comment: Vote based on the content of the question/answer not the status of the user.

Comment: Vote as you would usually. It'll help searches decide on the quality of the material.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Votes do far more than just give reputation to the user on the receiving end. They send a signal to future visitors that a post is, or is not, valuable (worth their time, works, etc.)

In an ideal world, votes wouldn't have *anything* to do with reputation, but the gamification system used by SE (quite effectively) does so. That said, the fact that your vote isn't giving out reputation certainly shouldn't stop you from casting it.

To your final question, yes, we want to keep good content around, even if the user that posted it has chosen to leave. Vote on it as you would any other post (and it certainly should not be deleted just because the user is gone).

Comment: Ya seems pretty correct and understandable. I'm thinking that I did a fair question based on a doubt even that I was downvoted. Well I will accept this ASAP :)

Comment: @dippas Could just be that the voters didn't like your premise, or thought the answer was obvious. I agree that its a totally fair question, and that you did a good job presenting it. Just don't let downvotes on meta bother you too much, they don't mean anything :)